# Run specific unit test in Visual Studio from the code window

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I know I can click items in the test-explorers and run individual tests from there, but I would like to be able to right click or use a shortcut key to run the test of the method that has the current focus in the editor.

There doesn't appear to be a "run test" item available.

Answer (score 1):

The best (but non-free) option is **[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)**:

[image]

Alternatives are:

- [NUnit Test Adapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) (free)
- [TestDriven.Net](http://testdriven.net/) (non-free)
- [NUnitForVS](http://nunitforvs.codeplex.com/) (free; Visual Studio 2008–2010 only)